# Como colocar paginação no foreach que retorna uma lista JSON com ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, foreach, paginação

Eu chamo essa função que me retorna uma lista e popula uma tabela na view, atualizando sempre que passo um parâmetro pelo filtro. Tudo funciona perfeitamente, apenas preciso colocar paginação, pois tem busca que retorna mais de 100 linhas. Pesquisei bastante, mas não acertei a usar os pluggins. Queria mesmo era só implementar no que ja está feito.

```
function CarregaGridCliente(representante, vendedor) {

        $("#tbl > tbody").empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Representantes/Clientes/Listar",
                mtype: 'GET',
                async: false,
                datatype: 'json',
                data: { representante: representante, vendedor: vendedor },
                success: function (data) {

                    $.each(data, function (i, element) {
                        $("#tbl > tbody").append(
                            "<tr>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_COD + "</td>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_LOJA + "</td>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_NOME + "</td>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_CGC + "</td>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_MUN + "</td>" +
                            "     <td>" + element.A1_TEL + "</td>" +

                            "</tr>"
                        );
                    });
                }
        });

    }
```

[image: Veja como a lista retorna certinho, preciso só colocar a paginação pra diminuir as linhas do resultado]

Comment: Isso pode ser implementado no lado servidor. 
Pode compartilhar o código do método *Listar* (Representantes/Clientes/Listar)?

Comment: Se quiser fazer no lado cliente (o que não seria interessante já que retornou todos os dados), pode usar o *DataTables*:  https://datatables.net/

Comment: public JsonResult Listar(string representante, string vendedor)
        {
            var listaRecurso = Dao.Get(representante,vendedor).ToList();
            return Json(listaRecurso, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: eu ja tentei usar o datatables.net . Não consegui adaptar com o codigo que programei

Comment: Por favor coloque o comentário com o código do método Listar na pergunta para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já tem um objeto do tipo `List` do lado server, você pode usar os métodos `Skip` e `Take` para paginar. Eles respectivamente "pulam" alguns itens e "pegam" alguns itens de uma lista.

Por exemplo, uma lista com 200 itens chamada *lista*, para paginar de 50 em 50, pegando a terceira página, seria assim:

```
var paginada = lista.Skip(99).Take(50);
```

No seu caso, o métodos ficará algo assim:

```
public JsonResult Listar(string representante, string vendedor, int pagina, int tamanhoPagina) 
{ 
    var listaRecurso = Dao.Get(representante,vendedor).ToList(); 
    var listaPaginada = listaRecurso.Skip((tamanhoPagina - 1) * pagina).Take(tamanhoPagina);
    return Json(listaPaginada, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Perceba que será necessário passar para o método **Listar** mais dois parâmetros, o número da página e o total de dados que quer retornar por página

Comment: obrigada, vou ler a respeito... Mas como ficaria meu front-end?

Comment: ai você precisa montar a paginação no front. Pode ser manual ou usando algum plugin, como esse: http://flaviusmatis.github.io/simplePagination.js/

Comment: ja implementei no controller, ja está retornando como esperado. vou ver agora como faço algo manual, sem plugin, simples mesmo, pra poder fazer o "proximo" e o "anterior" no front.
Se vc tiver um exemplo simples, agradeceria ainda mais. Obrigada Ricardo

Answer (score 2):

Para utilizar o dataTables é muito simples. Fiz um exemplo em poucos minutos. Siga esses passos:

Faça o download do plugin nesse [link](https://datatables.net/download/)

No step 2 marque a opção  jQuery 3;

No step 3 faça o download dos arquivos;

Descompacte os arquivos em uma pasta no seu projeto;

No head do seu html link os arquivos necessários conforme exemplo abaixo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DataTables/datatables.min.css">

<script src="DataTables/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables/jQuery-3.2.1/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="DataTables/DataTables-1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">    </script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

Na sua tabela identifique através do id:

```
<table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
</table>
```

O resultado final é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Para tradução utilize esse [link](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil)
- Espero que possa ajudar.